# Given 2 lists, find a random fixed-size subset from both lists such that there is at least one value from each list (preferably uniformly selected)

Tags: python, list, random

Let's say I have 2 lists, list 1 and list 2 such that( for example)

```
l1 = ['w1', 'w2', 'w3', 'w4', 'w5']
l2 = ['w6', 'w7', 'w8']
```

Is there a short and sweet way to get a new list (of a given fixed size, such as 4) containing words from both lists such that there is at least one word from each list? (No repetition)

Possible results for size 4

```
['w6', 'w2', 'w4', 'w8']
['w2', 'w8', 'w7', 'w4']
['w1', 'w2', 'w6', 'w4']
['w2', 'w3', 'w1', 'w7']
```

Comment: For this question, should the subset be chosen uniformly at random from among all possible choices?

Comment: @rdas, a subset from both lists.

Comment: @PeterO., Uniform choosing is preferable. But it should  at least choose one from each list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`random.sample()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/random.html#random.sample) for that:

```
import random

l1 = ['w1','w2','w3','w4','w5']
l2 = ['w6','w7','w8']

result = [random.sample(l1,2) + random.sample(l2,2) for i in range(4)]
print(result)
```

Possible result:

```
[['w5', 'w1', 'w8', 'w7'], ['w3', 'w4', 'w7', 'w6'], ['w3', 'w5', 'w6', 'w8'], ['w5', 'w2', 'w7', 'w6']]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can generate all of them:

```
from itertools import combinations

l1 = ['w1','w2','w3','w4','w5']
l2 = ['w6','w7','w8']

results = []
for parts in ( list(p) + [other] for p in combinations(l1,3) for other in l2):
    results.append(parts)

print(results, sep="\n")
```

Output:

```
[['w1', 'w2', 'w3', 'w6'], ['w1', 'w2', 'w3', 'w7'], ['w1', 'w2', 'w3', 'w8'],
 ['w1', 'w2', 'w4', 'w6'], ['w1', 'w2', 'w4', 'w7'], ['w1', 'w2', 'w4', 'w8'], 
 ['w1', 'w2', 'w5', 'w6'], ['w1', 'w2', 'w5', 'w7'], ['w1', 'w2', 'w5', 'w8'],
 ['w1', 'w3', 'w4', 'w6'], ['w1', 'w3', 'w4', 'w7'], ['w1', 'w3', 'w4', 'w8'],
 ['w1', 'w3', 'w5', 'w6'], ['w1', 'w3', 'w5', 'w7'], ['w1', 'w3', 'w5', 'w8'],
 ['w1', 'w4', 'w5', 'w6'], ['w1', 'w4', 'w5', 'w7'], ['w1', 'w4', 'w5', 'w8'],
 ['w2', 'w3', 'w4', 'w6'], ['w2', 'w3', 'w4', 'w7'], ['w2', 'w3', 'w4', 'w8'],
 ['w2', 'w3', 'w5', 'w6'], ['w2', 'w3', 'w5', 'w7'], ['w2', 'w3', 'w5', 'w8'],
 ['w2', 'w4', 'w5', 'w6'], ['w2', 'w4', 'w5', 'w7'], ['w2', 'w4', 'w5', 'w8'],
 ['w3', 'w4', 'w5', 'w6'], ['w3', 'w4', 'w5', 'w7'], ['w3', 'w4', 'w5', 'w8']]
```

- [itertools.combinations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) of `l1` generates all 3-long combinations of `l1` and adds one element of `l2` to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the lists and use a generator function:

```
l1 = ['w1', 'w2', 'w3', 'w4', 'w5']
l2 = ['w6', 'w7', 'w8']
def combos(d, c = []):
  if len(c) == 4:
    yield c
  else:
    for i in d:
       s1, s2 = sum(i in c for i in l1), sum(i in c for i in l2)
       if not (s1 and s2) and len(c) == 3:
          if i not in c and ((not s1 and i in l1) or (not s2 and i in l2)):
             yield from combos(d, c+[i])
       elif i not in c:
           yield from combos(d, c+[i])

print(list(combos(l1+l2)))
```

Output:

```
[['w1', 'w2', 'w3', 'w6'], 
 ['w1', 'w2', 'w3', 'w7'], 
 ['w1', 'w2', 'w3', 'w8'], 
 ['w1', 'w2', 'w4', 'w6'], 
 ['w1', 'w2', 'w4', 'w7'], 
 ['w1', 'w2', 'w4', 'w8']
 ....
 ['w6', 'w1', 'w7', 'w3'], 
 ['w6', 'w1', 'w7', 'w4'], 
 ['w6', 'w1', 'w7', 'w5'], 
 ['w6', 'w1', 'w7', 'w8'], 
 ['w6', 'w1', 'w8', 'w2']
 ....
 ]
```